# My sql select from multiple tables vs join

Tags: mysql

How does the following compare to a join statement?

```
 SELECT t1.name, t2.salary 
   FROM employee t1, info t2
  WHERE t1.name = t2.name;
```

would it be the equivalent to this?

```
   SELECT t1.name, t2.salary 
   FROM employee t1, 
   INNER JOIN info t2
   ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

or is it more like an outer join?

Comment: It is the same which you would know if you just tested it.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: @juergend why would someone use one method over the other? is there any difference at all?

Comment: Yes, the first one is legacy implicit join syntax and the second one prefered explicit join syntax which seperates the join conditions from the where conditions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Answer (score 1):

it will be like this without comma.

```
   SELECT t1.name, t2.salary 
   FROM employee t1 
   INNER JOIN info t2
   ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

To use INNER JOIN or LEFT or RIGHT or ... its up to you what results you want get.

related values or values which exist in other table and so on , here you can learn about the joins.

[image]

[SOURCE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)